# Problems with C++ Class Template Initialization

Tags: c++, oop, templates, object

Can someone explain to me why...

```
DataStructure<MyClass> ds;

cin >> size;
ds = DataStructure<MyClass>(size);
```

causes my program to crash, but...

```
cin >> size;
DataStructure<MyClass> ds = DataStructure<MyClass>(size);
```

does not?

I think it has something to do with my program using the default constructor and followed by an attempt to use the implicit copy constructor but I am not sure.

To give more context, I'm creating a hash table class and in the default constructor, I initialize the array with data to `nullptr` and in the constructor with the `size` argument, I create the array with the data to `new T * [size]` and set each element to `nullptr`.

```
Constructor without any parameters:

this->data = nullptr;
```

vs.

```
Constructor with size parameter:

this->data= new T * [size];
for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
{
    data[i] = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The `DataStructure` template is broken. Return it to the vendor and demand a refund.

Comment: `Foo a; a = Foo(bar);` != `Foo a = Foo(bar);`

Comment: Does `a` end up being the same value? If no, can you explain why not?

Comment: Maybe you can post you constructor and copy constructor

Comment: The constructors are posted and I don't have a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to declare a copy constructor. If you do not have a copy constructor then all members will be copied. In your case `data` will point to the data reserved in the second class. Next, this data will be destroyed together with the class and points to nothing. That will most likely cause your program to crash.
Your copy constructor should do deep copy, something like this:

```
DataStructure(const DataStructure &rhs)
{
    if (this->data) delete[] data;
    this->data = new T*[rhs.GetSize()];
    for (int i=0; i<rhs.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        this->data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that this was done for me with the implicit copy constructor so that I didn't need to write one. Thanks, uncletall.

Comment: Implicit will be that this->data = rhs.data, but that data will probably be delete in your destructor of your rhs object.

Comment: The shallow copy vs. deep copy strikes again :'( Thanks for saving me.

Comment: I added a delete[] of the previous definition of data to prevent memory leaks. Check if you need this.